# C Pointers and Access Violation Read Location

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C and still learning about pointers. I was just testing my understanding of pointers by trying to simulate appending to an array when I got an Access Violation Read Loaction error when using printf. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arraySize(int *arrayToSize);

void changeAll(int ***a1PtrPtrPtr, int nToAdd){
    int *bPtr = (int *)malloc((arraySize(**a1PtrPtrPtr) + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    while (*(**a1PtrPtrPtr + i) != -1){
        bPtr[i] = *(**a1PtrPtrPtr + i);
        i++;
    }
    bPtr[i] = nToAdd; i++;
    bPtr[i] = -1;

    *a1PtrPtrPtr = &bPtr;
}

int main(void){
    int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, -1 };
    int *aPtr = a;
    int **aPtrPtr = &aPtr;
    int ***aPtrPtrPtr = &aPtrPtr;
    int n = 4;

    changeAll(aPtrPtrPtr, n);

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 5){
        int temp = *(*aPtrPtr + counter);
        printf("%d is %d", counter, temp );
        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int arraySize(int *arrayToSize){
    int sizeTemp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (arrayToSize[i] != -1){
        sizeTemp++;
        i++;
    }
    sizeTemp++;
    return sizeTemp;
}
```

I get the error the second time I print in the while loop in main() when counter = 1. What I don't understand is that if I comment out that printf statement and look at the value of temp value in my IDE (MVSE 2013) it is exactly as I wanted and expected i.e. temp will be 1 then 2,3,4,-1.

What is going on please and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `*a1PtrPtrPtr = &bPtr` - you know `bPtr` doesn't even exist after that function returns, right? You're saving the address of an automatic variable that is long-gone after the function returns.

Comment: @WhozCraig That looks good as an answer, to me.

Comment: I'm slightly confused because I thought that memory was allocated with malloc until I free it. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Mick the memory at the address *held in* `bPtr`, yes; the memory at the address *of* `bPtr` *itself*, **no**.

Comment: Use `int temp = *(*aPtrPtr)++;`. Run your while loop `while (counter < 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in case you're wondering how this *appeared* to sometimes work, you really should [read this *stellar* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) to another somewhat related question.

In short, you're saving an address to an automatic variable from inside a function, then treating said-address like it is still valid after the function returns. That the automatic variable is a pointer referring to dynamic data is irrelevant. The variable *itself* is no longer valid once the function expires, and thus dereferencing its use-to-be-address invokes undefined behavior:

```
void changeAll(int ***a1PtrPtrPtr, int nToAdd)
{
    // NOTE: local variable here
    int *bPtr = (int *)malloc((arraySize(**a1PtrPtrPtr) + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    while (*(**a1PtrPtrPtr + i) != -1){
        bPtr[i] = *(**a1PtrPtrPtr + i);
        i++;
    }
    bPtr[i] = nToAdd; i++;
    bPtr[i] = -1;

    // NOTE: saving address of local variable here
    *a1PtrPtrPtr = &bPtr;
}
```

With how this is setup, the quickest fix is simply this:

```
**a1PtrPtrPtr = bPtr;
```

instead of what you have. This will save the dynamic allocation result to the correct location (which is ultimately the address held in `aPtr` back in `main()`). It looks hideous (and frankly, it is), but it will work.

Best of luck.